# Swing: How to position JFrame N pixels away from the center of the screen at first setVisible()?

Tags: swing, jframe

What's the code to position a JFrame N pixels (say 300 pixels in x-direction) away from the center of the screen before one calls setVisible(true)?

Answer (score 9):

I typically do something like the following to center a JFrame. You can add the offset to the `wdwLeft` variable as shown in the listing to move the frame off center. (The call to `setPreferredSize()` is superfluous and only there to make this demo work.)

```
package testapplication;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MyJFrame extends JFrame {

    MyJFrame() {
        super("Test");
        Dimension screenSize = new Dimension(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        Dimension windowSize = new Dimension(getPreferredSize());
        int wdwLeft = 300 + screenSize.width / 2 - windowSize.width / 2;
        int wdwTop = screenSize.height / 2 - windowSize.height / 2;
        pack();   
        setLocation(wdwLeft, wdwTop);
    }

    public static void main(final String [] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                final MyJFrame jf = new MyJFrame();
                jf.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
       );
    }
 }
```

You can add additional logic to assure that the offset window is still completely within the screen as determined by `getMaximumWindowBounds()`.

Comment: I think you should pack first, then call setLocation, using frame.getSize().

Answer (score 2):

Some info provide by the [Frame](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html) Javadoc, could help you to set location of your JFrame before the call setVisible(true)  with the setLocation() method

You can get the center point of the screen by calling [GraphicsEnvironment.getCenterPoint()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#getCenterPoint())

Answer (score 1):

Simple just set:

```
FormName.setLocation(X-Axis Coordinate, Y-Axis Coordinate);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
Dimension windowSize = window.getSize();
int windowX = Math.max(0, (screenSize.width  - windowSize.width ) / 2);
int windowY = Math.max(0, (screenSize.height - windowSize.height) / 2);
f.setLocation(windowX, windowY);  // Don't use "f." inside constructor.

                                   OR

Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
f.setSize(screenSize.width - 4, screenSize.height - 4);
f.validate();                // Make sure layout is ok
```