# setting layout of output windows in netbeans

Tags: swing, netbeans, layout, jframe

Is there a way to set the location of the output windows even before running.. My project has more than two forms , and i would like to display them in a non-overlapped fashion , and set their layout beforehand. ( I'm using netbeans..)

Comment: The best answer I can currently provide you is: Yes. 

You need to provide a bit more information. Are you using the Netbeans Gui Builder? What is the current behavior and what exactly is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: I have a control panel window , which has 5 buttons. pressing each will open a separate JFrame window.. By default , all these windows , including the control panel appear on the left top of the monitor. I want to modify this in a way so that the control panel alone appears on the left and the other windows appear to its right..

Comment: i changed the tags a bit.  I really doubt that NB has anything to do with this... but I will leave the tag on there for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question and answer looks like it might have info that will help you: [Swing: How to position JFrame N pixels away from the center of the screen at first setVisible()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685862/swing-how-to-position-jframe-n-pixels-away-from-the-center-of-the-screen-at-firs)

This q & a also has some useful suggestions: http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=100082